# How can I convert Date() to dd-monthname-YYYY in ASP Classic?

Tags: date, asp-classic, date-format

I searched but couldn't find what I'm looking for.

How do I convert a normal `Date()` in ASP Classic to a string in the format `dd-monthname-YYYY`?

Here is an example:

```
Old date (mm/dd/YYYY) : 5/7/2013
New date (dd-monthname-YYYY) : 7-May-2013
```

Comment: Note: your format specifiers don't match your examples. E.g., `mm/dd/YYYY` would be `05/07/2013`. The date you're showing is format `m/d/yyyy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```vb
Dim Dt
Dt = CDate("5/7/2013")
Response.Write Day(Dt) & "-" & MonthName(Month(Dt)) & "-" & Year(Dt)
' yields 7-May-2013

' or if you actually want dd-monthname-YYYY instead of d-monthname-YYYY
Function PadLeft(Value, Digits)
   PadLeft = CStr(Value)
   If Len(PadLeft) < Digits Then
      PadLeft = Right(String(Digits, "0") & PadLeft, Digits)
   End If
End Function

Response.Write PadLeft(Day(Dt), 2) & "-" & MonthName(Month(Dt)) & "-" & Year(Dt)
'yields 07-May-2013
```

I wrote an ASP Classic date handling object a while back that might be of use to you. It has a `.Format()` method that lets you pass in format specifiers just like the `Format()` function from VB/VBA. If there are any parts missing, I apologize--but this should be a giant leap forward toward natural date formatting.

```vb
Private pMillisecondMatch
Function RemoveMillisecondsFromDateString(DateString) ' Handle string dates from SQL Server that have milliseconds attached
   If IsEmpty(pMillisecondMatch) Then
      Set pMillisecondMatch = New RegExp
      pMillisecondMatch.Pattern = "\.\d\d\d$"
      pMillisecondMatch.Global = False
   End If
   RemoveMillisecondsFromDateString = pMillisecondMatch.Replace(DateString, "")
End Function

Function DateConvert(DateValue, ValueIfError)
   On Error Resume Next
   If IsDate(DateValue) Then
      DateConvert = CDate(DateValue)
      Exit Function
   ElseIf TypeName(DateValue) = "String" Then
      DateValue = RemoveMillisecondsFromDateString(DateValue)
      If IsDate(DateValue) Then
         DateConvert = CDate(DateValue)
         Exit Function
      End If
   End If
   DateConvert = ValueIfError
End Function

Class AspDate
   Private pValue

   Public Default Property Get Value()
      Value = pValue
   End Property

   Public Property Set Value(DateValue)
      If TypeName(DateValue) = "AspDate" Then
         pValue = DateValue.Value
      Else
         Err.Raise 60020, "Class AspDate: Invalid object type " & TypeName(DateValue) & " passed to Value property."
      End If
   End Property

   Public Property Let Value(DateValue)
      pValue = DateConvert(DateValue, Empty)
   End Property

   Public Property Get FormattedDate()
      FormattedDate = Format("yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss")
   End Property

   Public Function Format(Specifier)
      Dim Char, Code, Pos, MonthFlag
      Format = "": Code = ""
      If IsEmpty(Value) Then
         Format = "(Empty)"
      End If
      Pos = 0
      MonthFlag = False
      For Pos = 1 To Len(Specifier) + 1
         Char = Mid(Specifier, Pos, 1)
         If Char = Left(Code, 1) Or Code = "" Then
            Code = Code & Char
         Else
            Format = Format & Part(Code, MonthFlag)
            Code = Char
         End If
      Next
   End Function

   Private Function Part(Interval, MonthFlag)
      Select Case LCase(Left(Interval, 1))
         Case "y"
            Select Case Len(Interval)
               Case 1, 2
                  Part = Right(CStr(Year(Value)), 2)
               Case 3, 4
                  Part = Right(CStr(Year(Value)), 4)
               Case Else
                  Part = Right(CStr(Year(Value)), 4)
            End Select
         Case "m"
            If Not MonthFlag Then ' this is a month calculation
               MonthFlag = True
               Select Case Len(Interval)
                  Case 1
                     Part = CStr(Month(Value))
                  Case 2
                     Part = Right("0" & CStr(Month(Value)), 2)
                  Case 3
                     Part = MonthName(Month(Value), True)
                  Case 4
                     Part = MonthName(Month(Value))
                  Case Else
                     Part = MonthName(Month(Value))
               End Select
            Else ' otherwise it's a minute calculation
               Part = Right("0" & Minute(Value), 2)
            End If
         Case "n"
            Part = Right("0" & Minute(Value), 2)
         Case "d"
            Part = CStr(Day(Value))
            If Len(Part) < Len(Interval) Then
               Part = Right("0" & Part, Len(Interval))
            End If
         Case "h"
            MonthFlag = True
            Part = CStr(Hour(Value))
            If Len(Part) < Len(Interval) Then
               Part = Right("0" & Part, Len(Interval))
            End If
         Case "s"
            Part = Right("0" & Second(Value), 2)
         Case Else ' The item is not a recognized date interval, just return the value
            Part = Interval
      End Select
   End Function
End Class

Function NewDate(Value)
   Set NewDate = New AspDate
   NewDate.Value = Value
End Function

Function NewDateWithDefault(Value, DefaultValue)
   Set NewDateWithDefault = New AspDate
   If Value = Empty Then
      NewDateWithDefault.Value = DefaultValue
   Else
      NewDateWithDefault.Value = Value
   End If
End Function
```

Here's example code using the above class:

```
<%=NewDate(Checkin.Parameters.Item("@DOB").Value).Format("mm/dd/yyyy")%>
```

To get the format you've noted above, you would do:

```
.Format("d-mmmm-yyyy")
```